# Now she’d arrived she felt queasy inside

Tags: punctuation

I read this example sentence in the link: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/queasy?q=queasy.

> Now she’d arrived she felt queasy inside.

I think there is a comma or a full top needed between "arrived" and "she ~".

But Oxford dictionary doesn't show any of them. So what is the meaning of this sentence?

Comment: I would say  *that* is missing between *Now* and *she'd.* Comma or not, doesn't make much difference then.

Comment: A comma is possible(,) but not necessary (as in the sentence I have just written!).  The meaning is that she only began to feel queasy after arriving.

Comment: What @KateBunting said. The [relativizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativizer) ***that*** is completely optional in such contexts. And since it would be perfectly okay to ***speak*** this utterance with no significant pause after the word ***arrived*** it's also completely optional whether to write a comma or not.

Comment: @FumbleFingers H, thanks again for your generous attention. Hmm... Does that sentence mean this? `As soon as she had arrived, she felt queasy inside.`

Comment: You *must* use Past Perfect after ***now*** in this kind of past tense narrative (but note that Anglophones tend to avoid using ***now*** to mean ***then**, at that point in **past** time*). But if you switch to alternatives such as ***as soon as*** or ***once***, you don't *need* the Perfect form, so my advice would be to ditch it (it serves no useful purpose in this exact context), *As soon as she arrived, she felt queasy inside*.

Comment: Note [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=soon+as+he+arrived%2Csoon+as+he+had+arrived&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csoon%20as%20he%20arrived%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csoon%20as%20he%20had%20arrived%3B%2Cc0), showing how relatively uncommon it is to use the Past Perfect in constructions like *[as] **soon as he [HAD] arrived** [,something else happened]*.